# How to check if a reference to a function has changed

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have the following function.

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log('a');
}
```

I've then created a WebSocket.

```
var websocket = new WebSocket(HOSTNAME);
websocket.onmessage = doSomething;
```

Then, I've created an interval function.

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(websocket.onmessage == doSomething);
    console.log(websocket.onmessage.toString() == doSomething.toString());
}, 5000);
```

When the interval function runs, it logs `false` twice.

When I check to see what `websocket.onmessage` returns, it returns `dr(eA)`.

And when I check what `websocket.onmessage.toString()` returns, it returns `"function(eA){try{ey['Y'](eA)&&ez[d(143)](this,eA);}catch(eC){var eB=cI(cL(ey['C']),d(405));if(ey['C']['o']['tb'](eB,eC,(eA[d(314)]||d(636))+'.'+ey['ab']+':\\x20'+ax(ey['da'])))throw eC;}}"`.

How can I reliably check if `websocket.onmessage` is the same function as `doSomething`?